Why does using Range with arbitrary-precision numbers slow down computations, and how can I optimize?
I am working with some computations in Mathematica that involve creating several large tables and then taking a product and sum of their elements. I’ve noticed a significant performance difference depending on whether I use exact integers or specify a precision. When using exact integers, generating the tables is fairly quick, but when I switch to arbitrary-precision numbers (using N[*, 32]), the table creation becomes notably slower.
For example, consider the following code:
(* Using exact integers *)
m = 10^13;
n = 1336133617190;
k = 229589463125;
x = 30674724848;
s = 5*^-25;

AbsoluteTiming[
  a = m - k - n + x;
  b = k + 1 - x;
  c = n + 1 - x;
  
  i = N[Min[4 Sqrt[x], x], 32];
  xi = x - i;
  
  xs = Range[x, xi, -1];
  as = Range[a, a - i, -1];
  bs = Range[b, b + i];
  cs = Range[c, c + i];
]
(* Output: {~0.07, Null} *)

This runs quickly when using exact integers. However, if I define the inputs with a specified precision:
m = N[10^13, 32];
n = N[1336133617190, 32];
k = N[229589463125, 32];
x = N[30674724848, 32];
s = N[5*^-25, 32];

AbsoluteTiming[
  a = m - k - n + x;
  b = k + 1 - x;
  c = n + 1 - x;
  
  i = N[Min[4 Sqrt[x], x], 32];
  xi = x - i;
  
  xs = Range[x, xi, -1];
  as = Range[a, a - i, -1];
  bs = Range[b, b + i];
  cs = Range[c, c + i];
]
(* Output: {~0.27, Null} *)

Here, the timing is significantly longer. After generating these tables, I ultimately need to compute:
factors = xs*as/(bs*cs);
sList = FoldList[Times, s, factors];
Total[sList]

I only care about the final numeric result (the total) with a certain precision. I do not need each intermediate step at arbitrary precision. I want to achieve the final result as fast as possible.
How can I best combine exact arithmetic and arbitrary (or machine) precision arithmetic so that I benefit from the speed of exact integer operations for intermediate table generation, but still end up with a final numeric result at the desired precision? Are there recommended techniques or idioms in Mathematica to handle this kind of performance trade-off efficiently?

Machine numbers use hardware arithmetic. Arbitrary-precision numbers use library arithmetic.
